# Mock the fetchone() method of the Mysql Cursor class and set its return value to None

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, magicmock

I'm trying to make a MagicMock instance of the mysql connector, but I need for the method `fetchone()` to return None.

This is what I've done so far:

```
with mock.patch('mysql.connector.cursor') as dbmock, \
       mock.patch('mysql.connector.connect', mock.MagicMock()):
        dbcursor_mock = dbmock.return_value  # Get the mock for the cursor
        dbcursor_mock.fetchone.return_value = None  # Set the return value of fetchone
```

The problem is that this returns a `MagicMock` instance and not `None`.

Now, if I remove the second `patch()`, it does work:

```
with mock.patch('mysql.connector.cursor') as dbmock):
        dbcursor_mock = dbmock.return_value  
        dbcursor_mock.fetchone.return_value = None  # this does return None, Why?
```

But then my code will try to connect to the db and fail.

I'm using the MySQL cursor within a context manager like this:

```
def fetch_a_row():
# establishing the connection
with mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='127.0.0.1',database='mydb') as conn:
    # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
    # return the fetchone() output
    return cursor.fetchone()
```

How can I make an instance of MagicMock return None?

Comment: Try to nest your context managers: `with mock.patch('mysql.connector.cursor') as dbmock: with mock.patch('mysql.connector.connect'): ...`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use of patch.object() and side_effect

I have write a test which can be force `fetchone()` to returne `None` by the use of:

- the function `with mock.patch()` to get the mock object which avoids the real connection to the database (exactly as in your code)
- the function `with mock.path.object()` to mock the method cursor()
- `side_effect` instead of `return_value` to force `fetchone()` to return `None`

A test adapt for your need should be the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import mysql.connector

def fetch_a_row():
    # establishing the connection
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='127.0.0.1',database='mydb')
    # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # return the fetchone() output
    return cursor.fetchone()

class TestMysqlConn(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_01(self):
        # following patch() is the same you have used in your code
        with mock.patch('mysql.connector.connect') as mock_connect:
            mock_connect_instance = mock_connect.return_value
            # mock the method cursor() of the mock object mock_connect
            with mock.patch.object(mock_connect_instance, 'cursor') as mock_cursor:
                mock_cursor_instance = mock_cursor.return_value
                # force fetchone() to return None by side_effect
                mock_cursor_instance.fetchone.side_effect = [None]
                # check if fetch_a_row() return None
                self.assertEqual(None, fetch_a_row())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the code I have written the function `fetch_one_row()` which simulate your production code.

---

**EDIT**: I have edited the answer because the OP have add his code for the function `fetch_a_row()`.

### Test with the context manager

You have edited your question and add the code of the function `fetch_a_row()` with the use of the context manager.
When you use a context manager is called the method `__enter__()` (see [this link](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/)) and this method returns the object  `conn`. So with context manager I have to modify the test function as following:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import mysql.connector

def fetch_a_row():
    # establishing the connection
    with mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='127.0.0.1',database='mydb') as conn:
        # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
        # return the fetchone() output
        return cursor.fetchone()

class TestMysqlConn(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_01(self):
        with mock.patch('mysql.connector.connect') as mock_connect:
            mock_connect_instance = mock_connect.return_value
            with mock.patch.object(mock_connect_instance, '__enter__') as mock_connect_context_manager:
                mock_connect_context_manager_instance = mock_connect_context_manager.return_value
                with mock.patch.object(mock_connect_context_manager_instance, 'cursor') as mock_cursor:
                    mock_cursor_instance = mock_cursor.return_value
                    mock_cursor_instance.fetchone.side_effect = [None]
                    self.assertEqual(None, fetch_a_row())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I've tried this but even though it didn't work, it did give me more info. So I tested your code and it works as is. But in my case I was using the db connection within a context manager. When I added the context manager to your code, it also failed. Like this: https://pastebin.com/VDp1uXm2

Comment: @JuanKB1024 I have modified the answer to solve the problem of the context manager.